# iPhone GPS - Not receiving valid location updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

I have been working on a vehicle tracking app, which relies on core location services. Application is in test phase, last Friday it suddenly stopped working, there was no location updates at all (as if the GPS is not working), even when I was on my car and moving at speed of 30mph or higher. For the whole day app didn't work at all.

I checked out my logs, there was not a single location update for the whole time. However, at that time Maps app was working perfectly fine, which makes me believe that there was no issues with iOS/GPS-Module/Signal. On Saturday morning (the very next day) same app again started working without any changes in code or settings or re-install.

I have been working on this app for last two month and this is the 3rd time that I faced this issue, I'm unable to track the root cause since without any kind of changes the same build starts working again. I had this issue on two devices iPhone 3gs (ios 4.3) and iPhone 4 (ios 5.1).

So, is there anyone else who experienced some similar issue, or any tip on what could be the root cause or any hint to track such issues...

**...UPDATE...** 
Some updates: The statement above in the question that "I recieve not a single update" turns to be wrong, as I do receive very few location updates with worst location accuracy like +/-200m (with speed=-1 and course=-1). But in my app I require at least +/-50m accuracy. I had code to discard location updates with poor accuracy which caused me to think that no updates at all.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can edit your question.

Comment: hi @zee, i am also facing this problem, can you please share how did you solve this?

Comment: @Mohittomar I wasn't able to solve it (just ignored it as it happens very rarely). I also asked same question to Apple (like 4 years ago) and still waiting for their response.

Comment: I have developed these kind of 2 application in last 5 months, and have download EverLance app also. everlance works every time. but my apps still facing it.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my iPhone XS 13.3.1 multiple times. I am not able to get location in app, but other google map & apple map works fine. Other apps get speed & location very nice, but In my app it is not working. Same functionality working fine in simulator

Answer (score 0):

Did the app somehow lose permission from the OS to use the GPS hardware? Are you checking to see if location services are enabled by checking `+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`? I know that if you delete and re-build an app to a device, you have to re-approve location access. Maybe you accidentally denied it that one time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but thats not the case... as I wrote in the question, application start working without any changes to code/settings or whatever... which is really strange. I encountered this issue twice my client in an other continent experience it once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "significant-change location service", it might be interesting to verify that the locations where you did not get any updates had telephone signal. I believe the service is using cell change and not GPS to trigger the event.

Comment: No, thats not the case, everything works well except the GPS. I receive very few location updates with worst location accuracy like +/-200m. But in my app I require at least +/-50m accuracy.